# What are the three syntaxes to specify an ASCII character in source code in assembly code?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, microprocessors

I am taking a beginners course in how to program in assembly. I came across a review question that I can't seem to find clear information on anywhere on the web.

The question is "There are three syntaxes to specify an ASCII character in source code. Write three ways to Express the character *m* in assembly code."

I found an image which describes how to converts *m* into ASCII

[image]

According to this image, I'm assuming that in my code I can represent the character *m* as either 'm' , '6D' , or '109'. Meaning the 3 syntaxes to specify an ASCII character in source code is: ASCII, HEX, and SYMBOL. Is this assumption correct?

My understanding of assembly is very limited because we have not started programming yet.

Comment: Your suspicion is correct. These are three ways to represent the same thing. In MASM assembly it would be `'m'` , `6Dh` , `109`.

Comment: NASM also supports `"m"` (single and double quotes behave the same, but if your string contains single quotes it's handy to be able to use double quotes, and vice versa, like `"'"`).  And NASM also has backticks to process C-style escapes, so you can write `\`\n\`` instead of `10`.  See [ANSI escape codes not functioning when I printf them in x86 Assembly?](//stackoverflow.com/q/52459086) and [Different kinds of quotes in Nasm](//stackoverflow.com/q/6560355).

Comment: In the TASM assembler, you can also use `01101101b` (binary), `155q` (octal) or `155o` (octal) and I think it also accepts `^M` (Ctrl+M) for 13. So what is accepted depends on the assembler. What you use depends on how you want to use the value. If you interpret it as a character, you use `'m'`, if you see it as a byte value, you use one of the other formats.

Comment: FWIW, you don't **convert** one into the other. They are just different ways to represent the byte with value 109, in other ways: exactly the same thing.

Comment: Plus after assembly you have value 109 (encoded in binary bits), the machine code/CPU have no idea it represents ASCII character, that's just "interpretation" (probably enforced by following code using that 109 in logical way as "ASCII character", i.e. printing it or comparing with string data ... but all the time in 8 bits there's only bit pattern `0110_1101` and there's no other info (extra bit) storing "type" or "intent" or original formatting of source code)